# Is there a way to change the font size in the serch dialog Find and Replace with fields

Tags: emeditor

Is there a way / settings to change and / or increase the font size in the search / find dialog (field where text is typed, not talking about the label) ? Example with long regexp, it becomes non readable at all, (stupid) example:

**Find**: `^/drive/www-root/aw/([a-z0-9_]+)/(.*)xml$`

**Replace with**: `# necho " " >> /drive/www-root/aw_files/xsltproc_1.done nxsltproc -o /drive/www-root/aw/1/2html /drive/www-root/aw/resources/1.xslt /drive/www-root/aw/1/2xml`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QvgB.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't specify the font size in the Find box to any arbitrary size, you can make it use the same font size as the editor. To do this, select **Customize** on the **Tools** menu, select the **Search** page, and ensure the **Change Font for Find/Replace Drop-Down List** option is set, and the **Change Font only if Character Set of Selected Font is not System Default** is clear.

[image: EmEditor - Customize Search]

[image: EmEditor - Replace]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way for such tasks:

EmEditor can grab text from such controls via its tray icon app (emedtray.exe).

Run emedtray.exe;

Add a hotkey for Grab: http://www.emeditor.org/en/dlg_tray_index.html

Then click (to set focus) in the field you want edit; Press the hotkey;

The text in that field should be grabbed into EmEditor main window;

Then you can view/edit it with the abundant functions EmEditor provides (including Ctrl+wheel to change font size);

After editing, just close that window, the edited text will be sent back to the source field.